# Avoiding a for-loop to remove a slice of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list from which I get five random numbers. My problem is that I want to create a new list without the chosen ones. Of course I can do it with a for-loop but maybe there is a more efficient solution out there without the for loop or maybe with comprehensions for example.

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
some_list = random.sample(list, 5)
print(some_list)

for card in some_list:
    list.remove(card)

print(list)
```

Output:

```
[15, 2, 13, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14]
```

Comment: Could you randomly select 5 list positions (indices) instead? That would simplify the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would not have duplicate elements in your list, then you can use `set` and set difference, to get your result. And if you do not care about the order of the result.Example -

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
some_list = random.sample(list1, 5)
result = list(set(list1) - set(some_list))
```

Also make sure you do not name you variable `list` (for this to work) , since that would shadow the built-in type `list` and you would not be able to use `list(..)` to create lists.

Demo -

```
>>> import random
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
>>> some_list = random.sample(list1, 5)
>>> result = list(set(list1) - set(some_list))
>>> result
[3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
>>> some_list
[4, 1, 15, 14, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

```
biglist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
randoms = random.sample(biglist, 5)
newlist = [x for x in biglist if x not in randoms]
```

Comment: Unclear if the OP has duplicate elements, as this will remove all instances not just one as in the OP's original approach.

Comment: Thanks this is also interesting!

Comment: @AChampion So will the set conversion since collapsing everything into a set automatically dedupes it

Comment: Yes, set conversion automatically dedupes by the definition of set, and explicitly mentioned by @AnandSKumar.